# CircularSeekBar not showing in ScrollView in android

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm using CircularSeekBar (by Matt Joseph) inside my android app. When I add ScrollView on top of my layout file, CircularSeekbar is not shown. If I remove ScrollView, then CircularSeekBar works perfectly fine. I want to use Scroll bar in my activity, any help in this problem would be great. 
My Code as below -

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<in.company.appname.CircularSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:start_angle="180"
    app:end_angle="0"
    app:circle_stroke_width="16"
    app:pointer_radius="0"
    app:lock_enabled="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="4.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:textSize="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-250dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Above code doesn't show any seek bar.

Comment: Did you tried to set width and height for your scrollView?

Comment: @ hojjat - Yes, I tried that too but still does't work

Comment: have you tried setting width and height to ciruclarseekbar

Comment: @ Ramesh - setting height width solved the problem, thank you very much for solution!